# Cancel all active background workers when tabcontrol is disposed

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, tabcontrol

I am working on a large winforms project containing multiple sub-projects.
Everytime I select a new menu item, a different sub-project is initiated. Each project is using backgroundworkers to get the tasks done faster.

What I want is to cancel all active background workers running in a project if a new project is opened through the menu.

From what I have learnt so far, I must set the e.Cancel property to true for the tabControl inside the open project. I am disposing the tabControl but that does not interrupt the background workers running at that time and cancel them. I am not sure how to and which event to trigger for this tabControl in order to set the e.Cancel property value (if indeed that is what I should do).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Cancellation is "Cooperative", if the background worker is not designed to check the cancellation flag while it is performing its work you can't cancel it.

Comment: Ok, say the background worker does check for the cancellation flag...where should this flag be set?

Comment: Where?...anywhere you've got a reference to the BackgroundWorker and can call its [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: What I mean is, I need it to be triggered when the tabcontrol is being disposed. I have a variable number of background workers in each project, and a common method has to be written to cancel them all when the respective project's tabcontrol is being disposed. How do I ensure that all the background workers are being cancelled?

Comment: How are you creating these new "projects" and adding them to your Form?  My suggestion is you keep a reference to the current project so you can act upon it.  Then add a `Cancel()` method to the projects so you can call it.  That method will cancel all the BackgroundWorkers() within it.  If these "projects" are all of different Types, then make them implement an **Interface** that has a `Cancel()` member.  Then you can cast the current project to the interface type and call its Cancel() method.